# Calculation of Euler angles. But gets a change (delta) in change and not a constant value

Tags: math, imu

What I've done will now:

I'm using an IMU (MPU6000) to calculate the Euler angles of an object and for this, I'm using [Madgwick](http://x-io.co.uk/open-source-imu-and-ahrs-algorithms/) AHRS algorithm. The MPU gives acceleration due to gravity (a) about the axis and angular velocity (g) about the axis and I feed these values to calculate the quaternions which are converted to Euler angles using this function found on [Wikipedia](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Conversion_between_quaternions_and_Euler_angles#/Source_Code_2).

So what's going wrong:

1. I'm getting the Euler angles to be yaw-pitch-roll: 0.001518, 0.001626, 0.003990. This isn't in degrees or radiance. Whats the dimension here?
   I'm feeding in, the accelerometer reading about each axis (so its m/s^2) and after calculating the angle of rotation from the gyro, the theta value (in degrees) about each axis.

   ```
   MadgwickAHRSupdateIMU((float)tx, (float)ty, (float)tz,(float)ax, (float)ay, (float)az);
   ```

   where tx,ty,tz are the angle and ax,ay,az are in G.

       `tx = gx * timestep;` 
   where gx is the raw gyroscope reading. And timestep is the time between gyro readings.

Comment: Are you integrating the angular rate from the IMU? Otherwise, you should expect the angle output to be the instantaneous rate of rotation.

Comment: No, I wasn't. Now I'm multiplying the angular velocity with the time elapsed between adjacent readings.  Thank you. I've updated the question with my current challenge.

Comment: The gyro outputs are in deg/s, so you need to integrate. Something like this, each time you get a reading: Angle = Angle + Gx * timestep.  Your next challenge is that this will run away in a short time; you'll need to zero Angle and rate, with the device stationary, before you start. Corrected_rate = Rate - Rate_when_still.

Comment: Thank you this has been solved. The Madwick's AHRS algorithm needed the gyro values to be in rad/s and acc to be in any dimension.